# signature and functionality of selection callback of treeview in gtkmm

Tags: treeview, gtkmm

I have a treeview and want to get notified if the selection changes. What is the signature for the callback?

I found a code snippet like:

```
Gtk::TreeView *treeview = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::TreeView);
Glib::RefPtr< Gtk::TreeSelection > sel = treeview->get_selection();
sel->set_mode(  Gtk::SELECTION_MULTIPLE );
sel->set_select_function(sigc::ptr_fun(&SelFun));
```

But I can't find anything about the SelFun!

- How is the signature
- How to find out which rows and columns are selected inside this function?
- How to access data from the model with that object

Yes, I have actually no idea how the TreeView/Model/Path/Selection interacts. Every link to an example is highly welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want multiple selection. I had the same problem too. Once you have enabled mutliple selection, getting the selected rows is a little more difficult. The method of acquiring them varies slightly.

I'll provide the most general method. First, you need to overload the signal_changed() signal after you have enabled multiple selection. Then, assign the TreeView's TreeSelection to a RefPtr for easy access.

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::TreeSelection> TreeView_TreeSelection;
TreeView_TreeSelection = your_TreeView.get_selection();
```

Next, connect the TreeSelection to the signal_changed() signal.

```
TreeView_TreeSelection -> signal_changed().connect(sigc::mem_fun(your_TreeView,
  &your_Class::on_selection_changed));
```

Now, make sure to make a void function header in "your_Class" named on_selction_changed() or whatever you want. Just make sure to change the name in the connection above to whatever your class' name is.
The final step is to make the function. Here is a simple example of getting a vector of all of the TreePaths of the rows selected, then converting those TreePaths into a vector of TreeModel::Row pointers.

```
void your_Class::on_selection_changed()
{

  if((TreeView_TreeSelection -> count_selected_rows()) == 0)
  {

     return;

  }

  vector<Gtk::TreeModel::Path> selected_rows = TreeView_TreeSelection -> get_selected_rows();

  vector<Gtk::TreeModel::Row*> selected_TreeRows;  

  vector<Gtk::TreeModel::Path>::iterator TreePath_iterator = selected_rows.begin();

  Gtk::TreeRow *row;

  while(TreePath_iterator != selected_rows.end()
  {

    selected_row_it = p_TreeModel -> get_iter(TreePath_iterator);

    row = (*selected_row_it);

    selected_TreeRows.push_back(row);

    TreePath_iterator++;

  }

}
```

Do you know how to iterate through a TreeModel using the STL-like contain API called children() of a TreeModel? It's most useful for iterating over all of the rows of a TreeModel or getting the size (AKA row count) of a TreeModel. Its use depends on whether you're using a ListStore, TreeStore or a custom TreeModel.

Comment: Sorry, can't compile your code. I am missing: p_TreeModel definition and initialzation and selected_row_it definition and initialization. I am totally confused about tree, treeview, row, treerow, treerowiterator... wow! Only to get data from a selection.... :-)

Comment: Sorry. p_TreeModel should just be a Gtk::ListStore, which I assume you are using. Every TreeView must use a TreeModel. It is what holds the data of a TreeView. I recommend using this guide for understanding how to use a TreeView. You NEED to derive your class from Gtk::TreeView, like the guide below details. I'll improve this example tomorrow when I have more timehttps://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/chapter-treeview.html.en